# Rotating a heat map from a matrix in gnuplot

Tags: matrix, rotation, gnuplot, heatmap

I'm trying to rotate 45º a heat map coming from a matrix. The problem when rotating the discrete data is that the plot exceeds the window's size, reaching labels and tics place. Any idea or alternative to solve the problem?
Main code

```
set xrange[-20:20]
set yrange[30:50]
plot "test.txt" u ($2-$1+1):($2+$1):3 matrix with image notitle
```

And what I 
[obtain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTgO8.png). The data file http://www.filedropper.com/test_146

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest an alternative using `splot` with `pm3d` because the `set pm3d` has the option `clip1in` and `clip4in` which tells gnulpot which qudrangles to plot, but is available:

```
set pm3d map clip4in corners2col c1
set yrange[10:*]
splot 'test.txt' u ($2-$1+1):($2+$1):3 matrix with pm3d notitle
```

It will show some spurious triangles:

[image: triangles]
If you want to go for an interpolation, have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14580956/gnuplot-ignores-x-and-y-ranges-when-using-dgrid3d)

Pay attention that `splot [...] with pm3d` will draw the colors of the quadrangles, so that if your matrix s NxM, you'll get (N-1)x(M-1). On the other hand using `plot [...] with image` you'll get NxM quandrangles. (see `help image`).

Comment: Thank you for the help. It really solved my problem: since the martix decays to zero I can now use a background color to eliminate the "spurious triangles". However, it should be more problematic in a more general case